# Running different emulator for vs 2013 apache cordova

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, windows-7, visual-studio-cordova

I have installed the `vs 2013 apache cordova` successfully in windows 8.1 64 bit.

Now I try to run apache cordova in `Windows 7` using again the vs 2013 update 4 and the `CTP 3.0`. I have installed it and I have the ripple to run. I don't have hyperv

How ever I have the problem that:

In windows I can see three option in order to run my app. The emulator I want to use, the debbug option and one list from which I can select the operation system I want to use (Android. ios, windows phone etc). However in windows 7 istallation I don't have this option. What can I do to have this option?

Answer (score 0):

Previous to Windows 8 Hyper-V was only available in Server editions of Windows.  It is not available in Windows 7.

The base Android emulator (not the Visual Studio one) does not require Hyper-V. The iOS Simulator can also be used on a remote Mac.  Windows and Windows Phone emulators, however, cannot be used without Hyper-V.